# Salesforce is not able to get docusign authentication failure event

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, apex, docusignapextoolkit

I have enabled recipient failure event in triggered event in docusign.but still i didn't receive any reference in Salesforce after authentication failure at recipient end

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a Recipient Event for failed delivery similar to an envelope event

RecipeintEvent event = new RecipientEevnt();

event.setRecipientEventStatusCode("AutoResponded");

event.setIncludeDocuments("false");

Or you can activate it in your connect configuration under recipient events